# Spring-JPA Does not result in insert, after in readOnly transaction?

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, annotations, readonly

The persist/insert process does not executed, after transaction ReadOnly!

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="transactionManagerConstant" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="constant"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="constant" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JSFSpring" />
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public String workSaved(){
    em.persist(work);
    work = (Work) ctx.getBean("work");
    return "/list.xhtml";
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=true)
public List<Odev> getWorkedList() {
    return workedList = (List<Work>) em.createNamedQuery("Work.findAll").getResultList();
}
```

Exception: **javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.hakdogan.hakdoganjsfspring.entity.Work]**

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    ... 73 more

Comment: The exception message is usually followed by a full stack trace which helps diagnosing the error. That said, your code does not make much sense: it doesn't even compile.

Comment: The rest of the stack trace contains the useful information

Comment: Looks like you are using MySQL. Are use using InnoDB or MyISAM (in the database) and which dialect are you using?

Comment: Hi  Ralph. I'm using InnoDB, dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace.